# What would a good doc comment on a dart constructor look like?

Tags: flutter, dart

One of the dart lint rules is to document all public members, and of those constructors are included. Taking this statelesswidget as an example, what would be a doc comment for the constructor? All the parameters are the fields in the class, so I'm not sure what information should be conveyed in the constructor

```
class PQButton extends StatelessWidget {
/// What comment should go here?
  const PQButton({
    super.key,
    required this.text,
    this.backgroundColor = brandYellow,
    this.textColor = brandBlack,
    this.textStyle = const TextStyle(
      color: brandBlack,
    ),
    this.onPressed,
  });

  final VoidCallback? onPressed;
  final String text;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final Color textColor;
  final TextStyle textStyle;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make good, concise & easy to read documentation just look at native classes like this `MaterialApp` class documentation of constructor:

```
class MaterialApp extends StatefulWidget {
  /// Creates a MaterialApp.
  ///
  /// At least one of [home], [routes], [onGenerateRoute], or [builder] must be
  /// non-null. If only [routes] is given, it must include an entry for the
  /// [Navigator.defaultRouteName] (`/`), since that is the route used when the
  /// application is launched with an intent that specifies an otherwise
  /// unsupported route.
  ///
  /// This class creates an instance of [WidgetsApp].
  ///
  /// The boolean arguments, [routes], and [navigatorObservers], must not be null.
  const MaterialApp({
```

Or use plugins like MintLify or Copilot (but always fact check & add information that seems useful to you). Golden rule is- write down everything that you think is important. If you'd have to explain that code to someone, what would you say to them.

Comment: Thanks for the example, I've been putting "Creates a $ClassName" for the constructor but thought that couldn't possibly be the answer haha.